# Push parameter in controller is always null

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having a tableview. And in my didselectrow I get the right object that I want to pass to the next controller.

This is my code:

```
 id<NavigateDelegate> strongDelegate = self.delegate;
    NSDictionary * dictionary = [_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray * array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
    POI * poi = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@", poi);
    NSLog(@"Category %@", poi.rank.name);

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    DetailsViewController * detailsController = [[DetailsViewController alloc] init];
    detailsController.details = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:poi.name, @"name", poi.address, @"address", poi.details, @"details", poi.title, @"title", poi.url, @"url", nil];

    if ([strongDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(navigateFromTo:to:)]) {
        [strongDelegate navigateFromTo:self to:detailsController];
    }
```

Then in my delegate receiver I push the controller like:

```
- (void) navigateFromTo:(POITableViewController *)viewController to:(UIViewController *)toController
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:toController animated:YES];
}
```

But still my DetailsController his details NSdictionary is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the code of decleartion of details. and are you use storyboard or xib?

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and check `strongDelegate`'s value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The viewdid load is called before my setter is called.

So I changed the init method like this:

```
-(instancetype) initWithPoi:(NSDictionary *) poi
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        NSLog(@"Init DetailsViewController");
        _details = poi;
        [self initializeViews];
    }
    return self;
}
```

that way the controller has the poi details from the start.